# Laravel How to convert Model query code into DB::query?

Tags: laravel-5.8

**Code-1**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $posts = NewJob::orderBy('won', 'desc')->where('progress' , 'forwarded')->paginate(5);
   $clients = DB::select('select * from client_infos');

    if ($request->ajax()){
        return view('Admin.NewForwardedEntry.ajax', compact('posts', 'clients'));
    }
    else{
        return view('Admin.NewForwardedEntry.newjob', compact('posts', 'clients'));
    }
}
```

**Code-2**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $posts = DB::table('new_jobs')
    ->select('id', 'won', 'proj_name', 'department', 'district', 'time_estimate', 'proj_cost', 'proj_date', 'client_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'**strong text**)
    ->orderBy('won', 'desc')
    ->where('progress', 'forwarded')
    ->paginate(5);

    $clients = DB::select('select * from client_infos');

    if ($request->ajax()){
        return view('Admin.NewForwardedEntry.ajax', compact('posts', 'clients'));
    }
    else{
        return view('Admin.NewForwardedEntry.newjob', compact('posts', 'clients'));
    }
}
```

***Code-1 is working nicely but I didn't understand why the code-2 is not working?***

I am changing this code because I have to fetch data with two table **New_jobs** and **client_infos** where client information should fetch with new_jobs.

Comment: In code-2, It displays the error - Undefined property: stdClass::$title

Comment: what inside `$posts`  of your *code 2* have you `dd($posts)` it?

Comment: have your tried '*' instead of selecting each columns.? just check if its working.

Comment: Yes I tried but It is not working

Comment: getting the same error? `Undefined property: stdClass::$title` this means you trying to get title which doesn't exists in your code 2. have you tried diedump `dd($posts)`

Comment: object(Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)#328 (11) { ["total":protected]=> int(2) ["lastPage":protected]=> int(1) ["items":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#322 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#314 (12) { ["id"]=> int(146) ["won"]=> int(707).......

Comment: when used dd($posts)                                    LengthAwarePaginator {#328 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#322 ▶}
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8000/newentry"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▼
    "path" => "http://localhost:8000/newentry"
    "pageName" => "page"
  ]
}

Comment: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199497/discussion-between-devraj-and-danish-khan-i).

Comment: when you `dd($posts)` does it work ?

Comment: ok so do that again.. dd($posts) go to browser and `ctrl + click` so that all the text appears and paste it to your code above.